# Magento 2 Product Image not showing in backend and can't upload image

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-images, magento2.3.2

1) When Edit or add new product in admin (backend) the product image doesn't show up

2) When choosing an image to upload, nothing happens

3) I have checked Magento_ProductVideo::helper/gallery.phtml where data-mage-init='{"openVideoModal":{}}' not loading JS component of openVideoModal = Magento_ProductVideo/js/video-modal.js.

[image]

If anyone knows how to solve this please help me.